# Store results as new array

Tags: jquery, each

I'm building a questionnaire that has multiple screens (just split by `<section>`) and need to store each screen checkbox result as an array to be used in a query.

I thought using .each() and a dynamically assigned variable name would do the job, but my code does not split the arrays per section.

Any ideas how this can be done?

```
$('.product_selector .submit').click(function(){
    i = 1;
    $('.product_selector section').each(function(){
        section[i] = $("ul li input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
            return $(this).attr('name');
        }).get();
        i++;
    });
});
```

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/chops07876/pen/xXWVVy

Comment: try using $(this).find(“ul li input:checkbox............. or use the 2nd parameter notation of jQuery selector

Comment: I just get an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: section is not defined

Comment: define the variable section somewhere globally as var section = [];

Comment: Yep, tried that. It then says section1 (which I would expect to be the first section of checkbox data) is not defined when trying to console.log the data.

Comment: how do you want your data to be like?? can you show a sample?

Comment: I just want to be able to store each section as a separate array. Here's a pen of the code: https://codepen.io/chops07876/pen/xXWVVy

Comment: I think the code pen works fine. and I couldn't see any issue with it.
try `console.log($(this).find("ul li input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
         return $(this).attr('name');
     }).get());` and see the console.. everything is working.

Comment: Not sure it is. Why does console.log(step_2); return an error and no data? Should this not be the name of the array from step 2?

Comment: step_2 is not a variable in your code. if you where trying to log as "step_2" then quote it.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do. I would like the var name to be dynamic. The example above I tried increments, but this had the same issue as the pen which I hoped would be taking the ID from the current section as the variable. Does this make sense? Do var need to be declared if trying to create dynamically?

Comment: If you want to use dynamic variable, say for example "test" is the variable that you need then use `window['test'] = 'your data'`. and then in future you may use as console.log(test);

Comment: Good to know and thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to make your code like this.

```
$('.product_selector .submit').click(function () {
var result = []; // a variable to store the data.
$('.product_selector section').each(function(){
    // a variable to have each attribute.
    // the variable will have at least a blank array if none of the options are checked. In your previous code, if a section has no checkbox checked, then there wont be data for that section.
    var res = [];
    $(this).find("ul li input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        res.push(this.getAttribute('name'));
    });
    result.push(res);
});
console.log(result);});
```

I think the comments might be explanatory.

Comment: This will do the job :-) I can just print as per the nested array quite easily.

Comment: Thank you for accepting this as the answer and I am happy to hear that it worked for you.:)